# Quadratic programming limits to linear programming

Tags: optimization, continuity, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

For the quadratic programming A, if the coefficient of the quadratic term in the objective is zero then it becomes the linear programming B.

If we let the coefficient limits to zero, then will the solutions of quadratic programming A limit to the solution (or one of the solution) of the linear programming B?

Comment: yes, the solutions vary continuously with the coefficients of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is a possible way to prove that? Or do you know any paper on this topic?

Comment: Not sure if this bothers you, but in practice, most LP solvers find optimal basic feasible solutions and never a point in between.

Comment: Certainly not, take for objective function $(\epsilon x-1)^2+(\epsilon y-1)^2)$, with $x,y \geq 0.$ The minimum is $0$ at $(\frac{1}{\epsilon}, \frac{1}{\epsilon})$. Hence, the solution of the QP does not have a limit. Now, let $\epsilon$ converges to $0$ in the QP formulation, you get a constant objective function $1$, and the minimum is reached for all the domain.